# GPS機能がMonacaデバッガー上では動作するのにデバッグビルドだと動作しない

Tags: monaca

GPSで座標を受け取って検索するアプリを書いています。
Monacaデバッガーからプロジェクトを開いて実行した際には座標を取得できるのですが、
デバッグビルドしたアプリを実行した際には取得できません。

通知領域？（画面右上のあたり）にGPSマークも出ない状態です。
どの辺りを確認すればよいでしょうか？

一応、下記が呼び出し部分のコードになります。

```
//GPS起動
watchId= navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessGps,onErrorGps, 
    { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Comment: MonacaクラウドIDE→ファイル→Cordovaプラグインの管理→Geolocationのプラグインが有効になっているか確認し、有効になっていない場合は有効にして再度ビルドして試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！プラグインが無効になってました。デバッガーはプラグインが無効でも動作するのですね。

Comment: @ShinjiHorie デバッガには予め所定のプラグインがインストールされています。http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/debugger/installation/debugger_android/#cordova-plugins IDE上で行うCordovaプラグインの設定はビルド用の設定ですのでデバッガの動作には影響を与えません。ご参考までに。